# Replace dhtmlx dropdown arrow with Boostrap Select arrow

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, dhtmlx

I am working on a web application that uses dhtmlx `dropdown` and I want it to use the Bootstrap style. I currently simply try to add the Bootstrap class for a `dropdown`(`select`), but this does not change the *select arrow*.

Is there a simple way to style a `dhtmlx dropdown` to use the Bootstrap style?

In [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidgourde/d9s8gx2m/1/), you can see a dhtmlx window with a combobox on it. I added the Bootstrap class like this: `$('.dhxcombo_dhx_skyblue').addClass('form-control');`.

How can I change the arrow? And should I use another method? Am I doing it wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `dhtmlx` doesn't create a `select` and therefore the `form-control` class is applied to the div. Also, there are some custom styles applied to `div.dhxcombo_dhx_skyblue` which override `bootstrap` styles

Answer (score 0):

DHTMLX component enforces their own skins, so there is no simple way to reuse bootstrap styles. You can change the skin to "material", though. It looks more similar to bootstrap.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/d9s8gx2m/2/

It uses the same code, just a different dhtmlx.css file

```
var window_1 = windows.createWindow('window_1', 0, 0, 300, 400);
var str = [
    { type:"combo" , name:"form_combo_1", label:"dhxCombo1",  inputWidth:120  },
    { type:"button" , name:"form_button_1", value:"Set Req"  }
];
var form_1 = window_1.attachForm(str);
```